# слияние html и js

Tags: javascript, html

У меня есть сайт хтмл и я хочу добавить форму связи с javascript, чтобы после ввода юзера он видел свое имя и фамилию после сабмита. Как это:

```html
<label>Благодарим за отправку (имя и фамилия) мы с вами свяжемся!</label>
```

Мой вопрос. Как вставить эти данные в код html?

Помогите если несложно)

Comment: вопрос некорректный, знаю

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например так

```js
$('[name="button"]').on('click', function() {
    $('#rezult').html('<label>Благодарим за отправку '+$('[name="fname"]').val()+' '+$('[name="fname"]').val()+' мы с вами свяжемся!</label>')
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <input type="text" name="fname" value="Иван">
</div>
<div>
    <input type="text" name="lname" value="Иванов">
</div>
<button type="button" name="button">Отправить</button>

<div id="rezult"></div>
```

Comment: Небольшой нюанс: после отправки, а не вместо отправки ;)

Comment: Ни какой разницы по сути ) Или у вас страница перегружается при отправке?

Comment: Да, после отправки он ссылается на другой документ html

Comment: Тогда в ответе от скрипта просто пересылайте все сообщение со вставленными данными из формы.
Типа 
`echo '<label>Благодарим за отправку '.fname.' '.lname.' мы с вами свяжемся!</label>'`

Comment: @ЕвгенийИванов, это не у меня, но автор написал, что скипты сейчас не использует, значит, форма отправляется не ajax'ом ;) Впрочем, он уже в комментарии ответил.

Comment: @ЕвгенийИванов, в таком виде это дыра под XSS.

Comment: Ну и опять же ни кто не мешает отправить аяксом ))

Comment: @Qwertiy согласен про дыру )) Но не уверен что там скрипт какой то супернадежный. Хотя могу конечно и ошибаться.
Еще вариант из урл забрать кстати

Comment: спасибо за ваши ответы, пока еще чайник в скрипте, буду учить еще)

Comment: @Сamper успехов ;)